# App level gradle sync failed after following steps for connecting to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

```
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
```

Causes error:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)
says "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this after dependencies block

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
     def requested = details.requested
     if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '27.1.1'
        }
    }
}
```

It will remove this error!!